# Replace the n-th byte in a file with another byte

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, how do I replace, say, the 7th byte of a file with another byte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [binwrite](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-binwrite) method from IO class

```
IO.binwrite("testfile", [0x0D].pack("C"), 7) # => 1
# File could contain:  "This is0two\nThis is line three\nAnd so on...\n"
```

0x0D is 13

Also you may need to know about [pack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pack) method

Comment: What if I want to write an arbitrary byte to the file (not necessarily a visible ASCII character), say 13 or even 254?